# Submit form with attachments vis JS vs HTML format?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am not sure if this is pure Rails question or has some JS overlap.

I have a form that I am submitting remote via JS.  It works great and after submitted I have some JS callbacks in the `create.js.erb` file etc.

The problem is now I tried to add a file input to the mix.  Now when the form submits the request is processed as expected (record aded, uploaded file processed etc.) except that the request gets switched to HTML and not JS so I get redirected afterwards vs. calling the JS.  Example in my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @record, notice: 'Record was successfully created.' }
  format.js. ## only responds to this if there is no attachment
end
```

The form submits via JS if I don't add an attachment.  I may be missing something small here or am not understanding how file upload forms work in Rails

**CONTEXT**

Here is my form (other non-JS code and CSS removed for clarity):

```
<form id="new_feed" data-accept-type="text/javascript" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/myurl/" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" id="authenticity_token" value="M/X2dMfO3AIigopyJGQZDgKdlwP/Lwqwg+cLFbnP5jJ6W30NVKJANVTqeI/EXxBfXWYRo+ZHoBRbcKPdQf9siQ==">
  <input label="Upload Attachment" class="file optional" type="file" name="feed[uploads_attributes][0][file]" id="feed_uploads_attributes_0_file">
  <button name="commit" type="submit" remote="true">Create</button>
</form>
```

My JS:

```
$(function() {
  return $('#new_feed').bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    alert(data.name);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(event);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(xhr);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Form submissions with files are sent with the `multipart/form-data` content type which tells the server to parse the various parts of the request separately so that you can send binary data. Like `html/form-data` the convention is to respond as if the request was `text/html`. This is generally true of any web server and not just Rails.

Rails is just smart enough to change the content type automatically when you add file fields to the form.

If you want to send file attachments and get a JS response back you need to send the [`Accept: text/javascript` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept). If you're using Rails UJS built in `remote: true` handler you would do this through [the `ajax:BeforeSend` event](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers) - or you can just create your own Ajax handler.

```
document.addEventListener('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, details){
  let accept_type = event.target.data_set.accept_type;
  if (accept_type) {
    details[0].setRequestHeader('Accept', accept_type);
  }
});
```

```
<%= form_with(model: @some_model, html: { data: { accept_type: 'text/javascript' }}) do %>
```

Comment: This seems to be the right direction from what I searched based on your post.  I can't get this to work.  My form has the data attributes and I even pasted your JS into a plain old script tag on the page.  I even removed the logic and added a hard coded `details[0].setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/javascript');`.  As a test I threw in an `alert();` inside that logic and that doesn't fire when I submit.  It still should right?

Comment: I didn't actually test this code as the exact details depends on your rails version. Is the event handler not being called at all or is the if statement not passing?

Comment: I suspect not being called at all. That’s why I tested it with an alert. This is Rails 5.

Comment: I belive the event has the same name (but different argumens) in the jquery-ujs driver so it's odd that it's not being called at all. https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Comment: Progress... linked on that page: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/05/11/jquery-ujs-and-jquery-trigger.html.  Bound to my form and the alert triggered.

Comment: There is something else going on here.  I added a bunch of `console.log(data);` etc. to that callback and they work except for xhr which is undefined.  When I submit with no attachment that callback fires.  When I add the attachment it does NOT fire.

Comment: Hmm, I guess maybe jquery-ujs just doesn't want handle multipart forms. You could always just write a submit handler for the form that sends it with Ajax. When you're doing javascript responses you just eval the response by creating a script tag

Comment: Thanks for your help - this may be way over my head now and more work than worth it.  I may just make this a plain old HTML response.

Comment: Yeah doing it synchronously might be the easiest solution. If you update the app later you can use ActiveStorage which can stream up the file on the fly and just sends a blob id  along in the form data.